# How to implement this lib in a Custom Flatlist

Tags: react-native-popup-menu

i have a flatlist like image bellow. The code is this.
How to implement the pop menu in this case?

[image]

```
renderList = () => (
    <FlatList
      data={this.props.contracts.data}
      keyExtractor={item => String(item.id)}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <ListItem onPress={() => {}} listItem={item} />}
    />
);
```

Comment: hey guys, i implement this solution, but i have this warning 
_"in most cases you should not have more menu providers in your app (see API documentation). In other cases use skipinstacecheck prop"_
help me please

Comment: I inserted the image directly to the question to be always visible instead of displaying a url link.

Comment: Thanks so much,  kboul 2

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing special about rendering popup menu inside of flat list. Simply put it into your `ListItem` component.

Ad "in most cases you should not have more menu providers in your app (see API documentation). In other cases use skipinstacecheck prop" warning. Normally (like 98% of cases) you should not have multiple `MenuProvider`s in your application. If you put it inside of `ListItem`, it will be rendered multiple times. Just use one `MenuProvider` on the top of your applications - see main README:

> Wrap your application inside MenuProvider and then simply use Menu
>   component where you need it.

And there are plenty of examples where you can look into, e.g. https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu/blob/master/examples/InFlatListExample.js

Comment: Thanks so much! This popup menu is awesome!